# SQLite Net PCL slow SELECT query

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin.android

Im using SQLite on a Xamarin.Android App, and when I go to select all records on the table (about 44000) it takes about 25000ms , so, about 1700~ selects per second.

shouldn't the select be faster I tried some different things and managed to cut the time from 27000ms to 25000ms.

Heres the code:

```
    public List<T> SelectAll() 
    {
        try
        {
            using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(DATABASE_PATH, true))
            {
                Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
                w.Start();

                conn.BeginTransaction();
                var result = conn.Table<T>.ToList();
                conn.Commit();


                w.Stop();
                var millis = w.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                return result;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.Info(TAG + " - " + SUB_TAG, "There was an exeption selecting data from database: " + ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

is there something wrong with the way I try to select all rows from the table?

I tried to use conn.Table().ToList(), but it was about the same, just a 100ms difference

Comment: How many columns has one row? What amount of data are you loading approximatly? And are you using SqliteExtensions?

Comment: it has 28 columns as of now, I don't know if it could get bigger if the need arrises. Ammount of data? are you talking about the size of the data? it shouldn't be too much, since most of the fields are null most of the time. I am using SQLite-net-pcl nuget package, but thats about it.

Comment: I am using SQLite-net-pcl myself, but I don't have these performance issues. But then again I don't have a lot of data at the moment. I will try to increase my data to test it. Is it only on a specific device or did you test different devices (android, IOS, real devices, simulators,...)?

Comment: It's an android only app for now, so it's built on Xamarin android, but I've tried it on 2 devices, a Nokia 7 2016, and in a Xiaomi Redmi 5, both aren't phones weak enough to be so slow on queries

Comment: I've found what the problem is thogh, it's the ToList() method's fault, when I tried without it it toke 16ms-ish, but I only get an Enumerable<T>, whereas I wanted my entity's type...

Comment: That's very interesting. It would be nice to know if it is an Android-only problem. I will keep it in my mind and be aware. Thank you for the info.

Comment: The following could decrease your query time: 1. Singleton SQLite connection class.and using the same throughout app 2.No List Conversion until absolute `ToList();` 3. Not using a generic unless absolute. Also to be very honest 44000 is an overkill for a mobile local DB don't you think?

Comment: 44000 IS overkill, but I had to test for the worst case scenario, as of right now I can 5000 selects per secong. To be honest I think I'll just leave it at that for now, later I think i'll change the SQLite-net-pcl to GreenDB or ObjectBox, and see how that goes.

still, thank you very much for you hints, but I don't think the app would work without the ToList().

Answer (score 0):

It is at least unusual to leave the generic type. Since you already know from which table you are querying, it would be better to use `conn.Query<yourType>` instead of `conn.Query<T>`.
Same for `List<T>`.
Hope it helps.

Comment: in the query I am writing "FROM Evento" but that was just testing to see if it would increase performance, that is a base class of Type T so there are a lor of generic methods there, I'll correct the code. BTW I already tried making the query with the type of the table I'm using, the performance is the same, is 1700 records/sec normal?